# How did I get the announcer badge for this question?

Tags: bug, badges

Today, my achievement inbox told me I shared a link which was visited 25 times:

[image: Announcer badge]

However, I can't find any link provided by me [on the linked question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/audio-file-player-with-wall-clock-time-display). It seems I neither edited the question nor the answer.

Was the badge awarded correctly or is it broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the answer is simple - just looking at the [linked questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2602) (at the moment there is only one), you can see [your comment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/50728) posted under this question: [Audio player showing timestamps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/35191). (The two linked searches return no results - but you can test them with different URLs/strings if you wish to.)

It is worth mentioning that links from posts and comments within Stack Exchange network count too - this was different in the past, but it change at some point. (Probably it is documented better in some place, but at least one post mentioning this that I was able to find was this one: [Publicity badges might be taking internal links into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134185))

---

In general, some suggestions how to search for posts and comments containing a specific URL. In this case we would expect the URL to be in this format `softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2602/1935` - since it brought the announcer badge.

- The search modifier `url:` allows you to find posts containing some string in an URL [on one site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2A2602/1935%2A%22) or [networkwide](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2A2602/1935%2A%22).
- Stack Exchange software doesn't offer a feature to search in comments, but you can use SEDE. For example, here are queries to search [among all comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/1451220/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author-case-insensitive?word=2602/1935) and [among comments by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/softwarerecs/query/1261690/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-the-given-word-case-insensitive?word=2602/1935&userid=1935). See also:  [How can I search for specific comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23771) (I will add links to some posts from another meta - since those are the links I have at hand: [How to search among comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3917), [Searching in comments for a specific OP of a question and a word used in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32091), [How to search for a comment left by a particular user on my post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9460))